# python with app engine error import ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a problem with app engine, I use it with django.
I read a lot of thinks about the problem, but I never find a solution.
I use Pycharm for the development, I just use app engine in the models.py

For import ndb I make this :

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

There is my problem:
     If I use "dev_appserver.py ." I don't have any problems and the application work fine.

But when I use "python manage.py test mobile_backend/" I have an error.

> from google.appengine.ext import ndb
>   ImportError: No module named
>   appengine.ext

After some hours searching, the solution I have verified few things:

```
  -I put "'google.appengine.ext.ndb.django_middleware.NdbDjangoMiddleware',
  " in the top of my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES settings

  -I have the google-cloud-sdk.

  -I have in my .profile "export PATH=$PATH:/home/david/google-cloud-sdk/platform"

  -I attempt to change the PYTHONPATH to integrated the PATH of google-cloud-sdk, but without success.
```

Pycharm show me a problemwith the import, he know google, but don't know the end of the import.(appengine.ext)

I have search and I have the ndb module with this path :

```
 /home/david/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Have you tried adding `/home/david/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/` to your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Yes, but I can't fixe it..
And when I do this the error is : import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you are trying to use App Engine infrastructure but have not properly set up the App Engine environment. This is documented in the App Engine Local Unit Testing page in the [Setting up a testing framework](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Setting_up_a_testing_framework) section:

```
sdk_path = '/home/david/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine'
sys.path.insert(0, sdk_path)
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()
```

Comment: If I totaly understand I have to creat a file main.py to set up the App Engine envrionment? Where I have to creat it? For the test module Path how can I find it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have finally found a solution.

When I use

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

I succeed in importing google, but not the others.

I find the file import and saw just a google.py.

I created a symbolic link with my google in google_appengine.

After that, I can import google.appengine.ext, but I can't import ndb.

The error was

> ImportError: No module named yaml

For solve this I just make:

pip install pyyaml

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A symlink is a pretty ugly hack and won't work well in a git repo.

I recommend you go with R Samuel Klatchko's answer, which is the (more or less) well-understood way to inject App Engine's libraries into an outside script.